# NFT collection prices API?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, api, nft

I am building on Tezos (I am new here). I was wondering if there is an API for getting floor prices of NFT collections? For example getting the floor price of Tezzardz on OBJKT.com. If not how can I go about getting this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is an Endpoint by OBJKT.com for it.

https://data.objkt.com/graphiql/